# Mirroring Database tables and views on SQL Server Express

Tags: mirroring, sql-server-express

I need some idea on how to mirror all table and views in my development server to my demo server.

Both servers are running SQL Server Express.

I have tried it manually but it's very time consuming. 
I can try to replace the demo server virtual machine but that means deleting all data.

Comment: Restore database option is not time consuming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database mirroring feature is not present for SQL Server express edition. From question it seems you want to create a replica of your current database. In this scenario backup restore would be best. Replication would also not fit in your scenario as its also not complteley available for express edition(subscriber only is avaialble).

You can take backup of your current express database and restore it on already present database or restore it as new database. Backup would include all objects(views,sprocs,tables,indexes etc) present in source table. Since database has limitation of max of 10G( I am assuming you are using SQL Server 2008 R2 and above) it wont take much time to backup, copy and restore.

You can also create a manual backup job, copy job and restore job with help of CMD and a batch file. Please refer to [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958368) for automating jobs using windows scheduler and batch file. You can also [Schedule and automate backup job in SQL Server Express](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019698).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a question of replication, nor mirroring. Is about updating the app.

**You should have a deployment strategy for your app, including upgrade**. Updating the 'demo' would simply mean running the normal deployment of you app. Read [Version Control and your Database](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/). Study [Rails Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html), they're a great example of deployment control. Read about [EF Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx). Stop updating the DB directly. think in term of *source files*.